# Why output returning list and str

Tags: python, string, list, pandas

Say I have list of some unique Countries from dataset in Pandas

```
countries.head()

['Arab World',
 'Caribbean small states',
 'Central Europe and the Baltics',
 'East Asia & Pacific (all income levels)',
 'East Asia & Pacific (developing only)',
 'Euro area']
```

and I have filter 2 countries randomly,

**Update**: posted the code

```
In[]: countries_filter = random.sample(countries,2)
Out[] : ['Bhutan', 'Japan']
```

the again if I want to select randomly for **second country**:

```
In[]: countries_filter[1] = random.sample(countries,1)[0]
In[]: countries_filter[1]
Out[]: 'Japan'
```

when I check the type of countries_filter[1]

```
In[]:type(countries_filter[1])
Out[]: str
```

Output is `str` but when I remove the `[0]` from `countries_filter[1]`

```
In[]: countries_filter[1] = random.sample(countries,1)
 In[]: countries_filter[1]
 Out[]: ['Japan']

In[]: type(countries_filter[1])
Out[]: list
```

and check the type output is `list`

What is the role `[0]` playing here?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't run - you can't define ```countries_filter[1]``` unless you've previously defined ```countries_filter```. Also, this isn't how Pandas formats output. Please post your entire code and unedited output (or at least note any edits you make).

Comment: I have defined countries filter as `countries_filter = random.sample(countries,2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure, what's in your pandas frame, but if you change your code to the following:

```
random.sample(countries.head(),m)[n]
```

This returns as list containing `m` samples (in your case 1) from the list provided in `countries`. With `[n]` you select the n'th item from that list starting at 0 (in your case for 0 this corresponds to the first item).

I made an example for what might happen when you increase the `1` in your sampling routine - I figure this makes it easier to understand:

```
In[]: random.seed(42)              # ensures same output for all sampling runs
In[]: random.sample(countries.head(),3)
Out[]:
['Arab World', 'Caribbean small states', 'Central Europe and the Baltics']
In[]: random.sample(countries.head(),3)[0]
Out[]:
'Arab World'
In[]: random.sample(countries.head(),3)[1]
Out[]:
'Caribbean small states'
```

**Edit for updated question:**

The confusion might be because of the following reason: 
When you execute the first part of your code, e.g. `countries_filter = random.sample(countries,2)` there will be two items in `counties_filter`, i.e. `len(countries_filter)` will return `2`.

At this moment the second item (i.e. `countries_filter[1]`) is of type string. But now you are **replacing it** by a new item by executing `random.sample(countries,1)[0]`. As you are just replacing one element of the list, what you want is to only get the list content from `random.sample`, therefore you need `[0]`. If you didn't do that the overall result would look somehow like this: `['Bhutan', ['Japan']]`.

So the diffence that might cause the problem is basically: The first time you are **creating a new list** using `random.sample` whereas for the second call to the function you just want to **replace** one item from that list, therefore you unpack the list before using its content.

Comment: @Rohit: Your update matches pretty much with what I described above. I updated my answer to display in a more abstract way, which number expresses which behaviour. `random.sample` always returns a list, which you access as described e.g. [here](http://effbot.org/zone/python-list.htm#accessing). Did you expect different outcomes? I'm a little confused about what should be your final result.

Comment: Now I got it, actually I was not getting the part that `random.sample` is returning a list. So, `random.sample(countries,1)[0]` is returning the first element of `random.sample` list.right??

Comment: @Rohit Exactly! Glad I could help =)